# How to check if a product is already purchased using in app purchase in Swift?

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase

I have implemented In App Purchase in my App and those are working perfectly. When a user buys the stuff ,the button changes from "Kaufen" to "Abenteuer starten" but every time the User starts the app again, the button will show "Kaufen" again. If i press on Buy it works, the user doesn't have to pay for it again. is it possible that the viewcontroller checks the status of the in app purchase at the begining? "Kaufen" means buy;). Here is my Code:

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit



class TrailDescriptionVC: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var questionImage:UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var questiontxt:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var btn:UIButton!
    
    var quiz:Quiz?
    var products: [SKProduct] = []
    
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
        navigationItem.hidesBackButton = false
        
        

        self.title = quiz?.name ?? ""
        setupUI()
        if (quiz?.isFree ?? false) != true{
            let restoreButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Wiederherstellen",
                                                style: .plain,
                                                target: self,
                                                action: #selector(TrailDescriptionVC.restoreTapped(_:)))
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = restoreButton
        }
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(TrailDescriptionVC.handlePurchaseNotification(_:)),
                                               name: .IAPHelperPurchaseNotification,
                                               object: nil)
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if (quiz?.isFree ?? false) != true{
            reload()
        }
    }
    
    @objc func reload() {
      products = []
        if Network.isAvailable {
            startLoading("")
            QuizProducts.store.requestProducts{ [weak self] success, products in
              guard let self = self else { return }
              if success {
                self.products = products!
              }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.finishLoading()
                }
            }
        }else{
            self.alertMessage(message: "No Internet Connection", completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
    
    @objc func restoreTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
      QuizProducts.store.restorePurchases()
    }
    
    @objc func handlePurchaseNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
        setupIAP()
    }
    
    private func setupUI(){
        if let ques = quiz{
            questionImage.image = UIImage(named: "last")
            questiontxt.text = ques.trailDescription
            setupIAP()
        }
    }
    
    private func setupIAP(){
        if (quiz?.isFree ?? false) == true{
            btn.setTitle("Abenteuer starten", for: .normal)
            return
        }
        guard let product = products.first else {
            btn.setTitle("Kaufen", for: .normal)
            return
        }
        if QuizProducts.store.isProductPurchased(product.productIdentifier){
            btn.setTitle("Abenteuer starten", for: .normal)
        }else{
            btn.setTitle("Kaufen", for: .normal)
        }
    }
    
    static let priceFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.formatterBehavior = .behavior10_4
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        return formatter
    }()
    
    @IBAction func moveOn(_ sender:UIButton){
        
        if (quiz?.isFree ?? false) == true{
            move()
        }else{
            guard let product = products.first else {
                return
            }
            
            TrailDescriptionVC.priceFormatter.locale = product.priceLocale
            if QuizProducts.store.isProductPurchased(product.productIdentifier){
                move()
            }else{
                let alert = UIAlertController(title:"Danke!", message: "Mit deinem Beitrag unterstüzt du unseren Verein. Du erhälst alle Trails, für immer!", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let buy = UIAlertAction(title: (TrailDescriptionVC.priceFormatter.string(from: product.price) ?? "")+" / \(product.localizedTitle)", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
                    QuizProducts.store.buyProduct(product)
                }
                alert.addAction(buy)
                let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                alert.addAction(cancel)
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func move(){
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "QuestionVC") as! QuestionVC
        vc.quiz = quiz
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: `QuizProducts.store.isProductPurchased`, why not make this api call when the app is started?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are many methods for this, the first thing that comes to my mind is;
When the purchase is complete, you can save it to the phone memory with bool.

```
var purchase = false

    let firstopen = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "first")
    if firstopen {
        purchase = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "purchase")
    }
    else {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "first")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "purchase")
    }
    
    
    if purchase == true {
        print("already purchased")
    }
    else {
        print("not purchased")
    }
```

- The first time this code is run it will save bool as true in phone memory and you will always get true value after first run You will always get false if the code doesn't work.
- This data is deleted from the phone when the user deletes the application, but you can use the same code when the user says restore purchases.
- In short, the point here is to use `UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "")`. It's up to you to use it differently.